# Local Source Files missing while integrating scoreloop

Tags: java-native-interface, cocos2d-x, scoreloop

I am integrating scoreloop in my game  build in cocos2dx. I ran your demo project for iOS and it worked fine. When I tried to build android project, it game me error regarding local source files missing. Please view attached image. I have seen the file structure for relevant libraries and folders and all seems to be pretty good.

[image]

Comment: add the jni_scoreloop.cpp in android.mk file

Comment: I am not using the wrapper of scoreloop, I am just using the demo project provided by scoreloop which has precompiled so files of scoreloop libraries

Comment: did you download the scoreloop from github

Comment: The problem is, during scoreloop android project compilation, control can't find local libraries file of scoreloop. The path to those files are provided and you can see that line in the attached image which is 22.

Comment: Nop, I downloaded scoreloop SDK from development portal. The github contains the wrapper upSL for scoreloop.